# https post failure c++

Tags: c++, curl, http-post

I try to access the https://api.binance.com/wapi/v3/withdraw.html Endpoint of the Binance API

I need to send it as post order with my API key in a header and the parameters in the request body.

My code is Written in c++ and i am using libcurl.

The hmac_sha256() function is also working.

I have this code:

```
bool BinanceAPI::make_Withdrawal(string api_key , string secret_key ,string asset , string address , double amount , string &id ){

    cout << "BINANCE: MAKE WITHDRAWAL"<<endl;

    ArbUtils au;
    Json::Value result;
    CURL * hand;

    bool ret = false;

    hand = curl_easy_init();

    string url = "https://api.binance.com/wapi/v3/withdraw.html";

    string post_data("asset=");
    post_data.append( asset);

    post_data.append("&address=");
    post_data.append(address);

    post_data.append( "&amount" );
    post_data.append( to_string(amount) );

    post_data.append( "&timestamp=" );
    post_data.append( to_string(au.get_msTime() ) );

    string signature = hmac_sha256( secret_key.c_str() , post_data.c_str());

    post_data.append( "&signature=" );
    post_data.append( signature );

    vector<string>extra_http_header;
    string header_chunk("X-MBX-APIKEY: ");
    header_chunk.append( api_key );
    extra_http_header.push_back( header_chunk );

    string str_result;

    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_URL , url.c_str() );
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION , BinanceAPI::callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_WRITEDATA , &str_result );
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING , "gzip" );
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_POST , 1);

    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
    for(int i= 0 ; i < extra_http_header.size() ; i++){

        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk , extra_http_header[i].c_str() );
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(hand , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , post_data.c_str() );

    CURLcode res;

    res = curl_easy_perform(hand);

    curl_easy_cleanup(hand);
}
```

Well i now get the a errormessage from the server :

code: -1105
msg: "parameter 'payload' was empty"

I tried and asked the support but they don't know the answer neither. 
I don't know why that is the case tho. I have other endpoints accessed by the same structure which also need that exact same form and they work.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the same problem for some days now. Just got it fixed. My code is in python tho. Hope you can reference it.

```
import time, hmac, hashlib, urllib, json, requests

key = "my key"
secret_key = "my sk"
asset = "BTC"
addr = "abcdef" #btc address
amount = 1
timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000) #timestamp in ms

#the request parameters
request_body = {"asset": asset, "address": addr, \
                "amount": amount, "timestamp": timestamp}

#sign the request parameters with the secret key
#urllib.parse.urlencode(request_body) convert request body to a query string format

signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, "utf-8"), \
                     bytes(urllib.parse.urlencode(request_body), "utf-8"), \
                     hashlib.sha256).digest().hex()

#add the signature to the request parameters
request_body["signature"] = signature

header = {"X-MBX-APIKEY": key, \
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

#append the query string to the url
url = "https://api.binance.com/wapi/v3/withdraw.html?" +\
       urllib.parse.urlencode(request_body)

response = requests.post(url, headers=header) #send post request
print(response.json())
```

The problem is from the poor documentation. The endpoint requires a post request but it fails if the request body is sent alone and works if the query string is sent rather. Hope it helps.